# PPPoE Session Establishment

Tags: router, pppoe

From what I have understood till now about PPPoE protocol.

1. The CPE (RG) is the PPPoE client which connects to the BNG and establishes a session.
2. The session is always alive unless the CPE is unplugged.

My question:

When I have two host devices connected to my CPE, will both of my devices use the existing PPPoE session (already established when I setup my CPE) for internet access ? 
Or will both the devices have two different PPPoE sessions ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The CPE would establish the PPPoE session with the provider and terminate the WAN connectivity.  Hosts would sit on the LAN and have no knowledge of PPPoE.  The hosts send any Internet bound traffic to their default gateway (the CPE) and the CPE routes the traffic onwards through the PPPoE session.  So, both hosts use the same PPPoE session, but indirectly, they don't have any awareness that the session exists, but their Internet bound traffic will pass over the session.   So to answer your question, there is only one PPPoE session, the hosts do not establish their own, they do not know it exists, all their traffic (Internet bound) passes over the same PPPoE session.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I have a better understanding :)

Comment: @maverick No problem, if you are happy this answers your question please mark the question as answered